# Get two inputs per row & modify submit width

Tags: html, css, forms

I am currently coding my first website, so far everything is going well 'til I hit an obstacle. I am currently creating my contact form which I want to integrate into the home page.

I want the 2x Name and 2x Email inputs side by side (with a little breathing space between the two of course) and the text area to be the same width across the two boxes. I am also trying to make the send button be underneath the message box on the right side.

Also, I cant add a placeholder on the textarea. When I do that the text looks really funny and not like the other inputs. If someone could help me with that too it'll be really appreciated.

I have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work for me. I was hoping somebody here would maybe know a method I haven't tried.

I have added my code below for everyone to have a look at, to understand further what I am talking about.

```css
.section4 {
  background: whitesmoke;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-wrap {
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.form-text {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact,
input,
textarea,
button {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: .5vh .5vw;
}

.contact-full {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.contact,
input,
textarea,
button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5vh;
}

button {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: static;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: #c71d6f;
  border-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

button:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background: #c71d6f;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section4">
    <form>
      <h2 class="form-text">let's work together!</h2>
      <div class="contact-wrap">
        <div class="contact">
          <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          <input type="name" id="company" placeholder="Company">
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          <input type="tel" id="telephone" placeholder="Contact">
          <textarea class="contact-full" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
          <button class="button">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you are not doing this for learning, try using [https://getbootstrap.com/] which can make things a lot easier

Comment: I am trying to learn an similar code to <br> for forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grid-gap` to give the gap between elements and `grid-column` to align the element `left` or `right`. Check below snippet.

```css
.section4 {
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.contact-wrap {
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.form-text {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.contact-full {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.contact,
input,
textarea,
button {
  padding: 1.5vh;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: static;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: #c71d6f;
  border-image: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

button:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background: #c71d6f;
  background: linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #c71d6f 0%, #e36a64 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:500,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section4">
    <form>
      <h2 class="form-text">let's work together!</h2>
      <div class="contact-wrap">
        <div class="contact">
          <input type="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          <input type="name" id="company" placeholder="Company">
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          <input type="tel" id="telephone" placeholder="Contact">
          <textarea class="contact-full" name="message" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <button class="button">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```